`navigator.clipboard.readText()` triggers a "paste" context menu on Safari 17
I'm trying to find a way to hide the 'paste' context menu on safari when a programmatic paste is triggered. Does anyone have experience doing something like this?
PS: By "programmatic paste" I mean something like:
const copiedText = navigator.clipboard.readText();
document.getElementById("myTextarea").innerHTML = copiedText;

